# Can I run a DHCP server using Docker Swarm?

Tags: networking, docker, dhcp

I am using PiHole inside Docker as my DNS server, I want to enable the DHCP server functionality but I am running in Docker Swarm and I am not certain if it can handle broadcast requests at least it's not showing with  `sudo nmap --script=broadcast-dhcp-discover`.

Is it even possible or do I need to use `docker compose`

https://docs.pi-hole.net/docker/DHCP/ doesn't say anything specific about Swarm.

Here's my yaml segment

```yaml
pihole:
  image: pihole/pihole
  ports:
  - "53:53/tcp"
  - "53:53/udp"
  - target: 67
    published: 67
    protocol: udp
    mode: host
  environment:
    PIHOLE_DNS_: 1.1.1.1;1.0.0.1;9.9.9.9;8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4
    FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4: 192.168.0.11
    DHCP_ACTIVE: "true"
    DHCP_START: 192.168.0.100
    DHCP_END: 192.168.0.250
    DHCP_ROUTER: 192.168.0.1
  cap_add:
  - NET_ADMIN
```